# Why do i get a NullPointerException at If statement in do while loop when reading a simple textfile in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, bufferedreader, do-while

I'm new in Java, I have a lot of work with text and I've got an idea to make a simple program to do my work. I'm getting error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.text.work.Main.main(Main.java:25)`

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int someNumber = 0;
    PrintWriter saveFileOne = new PrintWriter("save.txt");
    PrintWriter saveFileTwo = new PrintWriter("otherThings.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("read.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String word = bufferedReader.readLine();


    do {
        word = bufferedReader.readLine();

        if (word.toString().equals("true")) { //this is line 25
            saveFileOne.println("No: " + ++someNumber + " = " + word);
        } else {
            saveFileTwo.println("Yes: " + someNumber + " = " + word);
        }

    } while (word != null);
    saveFileOne.close();
    saveFileTwo.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

}
```

Comment: what is your full code?

Comment: And which is line 25?

Comment: Give us more code and check the content of word before your if, your BufferReader.readline() probably returns nothing.

Comment: what did you input in the bufferedReader (i guess something from the console)?

Comment: Obviously `word` is null.

Comment: NullPointerException means that (duh!) a pointer, er, reference was null when used for some sort of object access.  In your flagged line `word` is the only explicit reference, and if it were non-null `toString` would be guaranteed to produce a non-null result, so most certinaly `word` is null.  And if you read the spec for BufferedReader.readLine you will see that it returns a null if "end of stream" has been reached.  So you need to compare `word` to null before attempting to use it with toString.

Comment: By the way, since BufferedReader.readLine returns a String, calling toString is redundant -- you already have a string, and toString is essentially a no-op that just returns the input pointer.

Comment: Also you are skipping the check for the first line in your `read.txt` because you read once before the loop and when you enter, you read one more time!!!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the second BufferedReader.readLine at the top of the loop, since you did it outside the loop (and doing it twice in a row will "lose" one line).  Move it to the bottom of the loop, where it will "refresh" `word` for the next iteration.  Then you don't need a separate `if` statement to "guard" against a null result, but can simply let the `while` condition cover that.  (And changing the `do/while` to a `while` will eliminate the problem of a null on the very first iteration.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've the same problem today, two addidional brackets is the answer

`(word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`

Answer (score 4):

From the [BufferedReader#readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) documentation:

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>   any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has
>   been reached

This means you've obviously reached the end of the stream.

If I were you, I would change the loop with a `while` one.

```
while ((word = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
 ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my first java program :) I knew that there is a some simple mistake :)

Answer (score 4):

Obviously `word` is `null` because  `bufferedReader.`[readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)`()` encountered the end of the stream and returned `null`.

You should do the check against `null` before entering the while body

```
while(null != (word = bufferedReader.readLine())) {
}
```

and to avoid such NPEs in general while comparing with constants call `equals` this way:

```
"true".equals(other string) // "true" is never null
```

Comment: Yoda conditions this is called.

Comment: @nachokk sense it makes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `word` is not null. Change the code as following code snippet.

```
 do {
       word = bufferedReader.readLine();
       if(word != null) { //If word is null, no need to go in if block
         if (word.toString().equals("true")) {
            saveFileOne.println("No: " + ++someNumber + " = " + word);
         } else {
            saveFileTwo.println("Yes: " + someNumber + " = " + word);
         }
       }

    } while (word != null);
```

You can also change your loop for reading a file can done easily using following code

```
   if(buffer != null) {
        while ((word = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
           if (word.toString().equals("true")) {
               saveFileOne.println("No: " + ++someNumber + " = " + word);
           } else {
               saveFileTwo.println("Yes: " + someNumber + " = " + word);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still the same `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.text.work.Main.main(Main.java:25)`

Comment: Give the FULL stackstace. On line 25 that was the only reason behind NPE.

Comment: what's in your `read.txt`? it looks like some blank lines are causing the problem